# Wordpress: How to redirect (or change) permalinks to a WP_query loop?

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, permalinks

So I have a page called 'comics' which uses a custom template containing a WP_query loop of the posts in my site (1 comic strip per page, with prev/next buttons for navigation). I also have an archive page that lists down all the posts within the 'comics' category.

By default, the links on the archive page link to the specific post itself, but how can I change it to link to the post in the WP_query loop?

I know I can use 301 redirect plugins and put in the correct link for every post, but I'm doing this for a client so it would be better if I could make things easier for her.

If you need to know, here's the WP_query loop in the comics.php page:

```
<?php 
$comics_loop = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
        'category_name' => comics
    )
);

if($comics_loop->have_posts()) :

echo '<ul class="comic-slider-container">';

while($comics_loop->have_posts()) : $comics_loop->the_post();
?>
    <li><h1 id="comic-slider-title" class="page-title">Weekly Comics &nbsp;|&nbsp; <span class="title-alt"><?php the_title(); ?></span>&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/category/comics/" id="archive-button" class="big-button">Archives</a></h1></li>
    <li><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'full' ); ?></li>

    <li><?php the_content(); ?></li>

    <li><p class="byline vcard">
        <?php
            printf(__('Posted <time class="updated" datetime="%1$s" pubdate>%2$s</time>', 'bonestheme'), get_the_time('Y-m-j'), get_the_time(__('F jS, Y', 'bonestheme')) );
            ?>
        </p>
    </li>
<?php
endwhile;

echo "</ul>";
?>
```

and the archive page's title links by default:

```
<h3 class="h2"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
```

Comment: change it to link to which post?

Comment: @Mark any post. e.g. I want Post #2 in the archive to link to Post #2 in the page containing the wp_query loop, not to the actual post itself.

Comment: what is Post #2 in the wp_query page? its another page? a section? you have any more specific info?

Comment: @Mark yes it's another page. I duplicated the page.php file to create another page template called comics.php. And within comics.php I added in the wp_query loop.
Right now Post #2 is at http://localhost:8888/wordpress/comics/page/2/, which is correct.
But from the archives, Post #2 links to http://localhost:8888/wordpress/post-2/. 
Is it possible to do it the way I want?

Comment: ah ok - is 'comics' a custom taxonomy?

Comment: @Mark ahh is that a yes if it has its own category called 'comics'? sorry not that good with wordpress terms :[

Answer (score 0):

In order to have your posts with that permalink structure - you should use a [custom taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies#Custom_Taxonomies).

That being said - if you haven't set one up here's a code to set up one for comics. Drop this into your functions.php

```
add_action( 'init', 'build_taxonomies', 0 );

    function build_taxonomies() {
        register_taxonomy( 'comics', 'post', array( 'hierarchical' => true, 'label' => 'Comics', 'query_var' => true, 'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'comics', 'with_front' => false, 'hierarchical' => true ) ) );
    }
```

and then to echo out a list of the links

```
$terms = get_terms('comics');
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    //Always check if it's an error before continuing. get_term_link() can be finicky sometimes
    $term_link = get_term_link( $term, 'comics' );
    if( is_wp_error( $term_link ) )
        continue;
    //We successfully got a link. Print it out.
    echo '<li><a href="' . $term_link . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

edit accordingly for your needs

Comment: Alright I tried your suggestion.. then went to read about taxonomies and such, and realised it's not quite what I needed... or so I think. Decided to ditch this method and do it another way (with a little lack of features still), since I'm running short of time. Thanks anyway!